# Finding the Maximum value.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

> Maximize $xy^2$ on the ellipse $b^2x^2 +a^2y^2= a^2b^2$

The steps I tried to solve:

$$\nabla f = (y^2,2yx)\lambda\qquad g = (2xb^2,2y^2a^2)\lambda$$

$$y^2= 2xb^2\lambda$$

$$2yx= 2y^2a^2\lambda$$

---

$$
\left.
\begin{array}{l}
\text{}&y^2= 2xb^2\lambda\\
\text{}&
\end{array}
\right\}
*a^2y
$$

$$
\left.
\begin{array}{l}
\text{}&2yx= 2y^2a^2\lambda\\
\text{}&
\end{array}
\right\}
*b^2x
$$

---

$$y^3a^2= 2yxa^2b^2 \lambda$$

$$2yx^2b^2 = 2y^2a^2b^2x\lambda$$

$\color{maroon}{\mathbf{Equalize}}$

---

$$2a^2b^2xy = 2a^2b^2xy^2$$

$$y=1$$

My main problem is which equations does one set each equal to. If anyone knows which one equals the other this will lead me to the right place in finding the solution.

Comment: I think you're missing a $\lambda$ in the first of the two equations where you set $\nabla f$ and $\lambda \nabla g$ equal.

Comment: I thought that they canceled out.

Comment: No, because there's no $\lambda$ in the expression for $\nabla f$, and nothing to cancel out.

Comment: Sorry misread your post.

Comment: Try $y^3a^2= 2yxa^2b^2 λ \to y^2a^2= 2xa^2b^2 λ$ or $y = 0$

Comment: Why does $y = 0$? Sorry I just do not get it.

Comment: There’s a common factor of $y$ on both sides, so $y=0$ is a possible solution. Note that your $g_y$ is incorrect. That’s going to throw everything else off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, transform your equation:
$$b^2x^2+a^2y^2=a^2b^2$$
$$a^2y^2=a^2b^2-b^2x^2$$
$$y^2=b^2-\frac{b^2}{a^2}x^2$$
$$xy^2=b^2x-\frac{b^2}{a^2}x^3$$
Next, differentiate and solve to find extrema:
$$b^2-3\frac{b^2}{a^2}x^2=0$$
$$b^2=3\frac{b^2}{a^2}x^2$$
$$a^2=3x^2$$
$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}a$$
Finally, evaluate $xy^2$ at $x=+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}a$:
$$xy^2=b^2x-\frac{b^2}{a^2}x^3=b^2\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\frac{a^3}{3\sqrt{3}}=\frac{ab^2}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{ab^2}{3\sqrt{3}}=\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}ab^2$$
That's your maximum. The minimum is at $x=-\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}a$:
$$xy^2=b^2x-\frac{b^2}{a^2}x^3=-b^2\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\frac{a^3}{3\sqrt{3}}=-\frac{ab^2}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{ab^2}{3\sqrt{3}}=-\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}ab^2$$

Wolfram Alpha [seems to agree](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%20x*y%5E2%20in%20b%5E2*x%5E2%2Ba%5E2*y%5E2%3Da%5E2*b%5E2).

P.S. Let's also solve the original equation for $y$ at $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}a$:
$$b^2x^2+a^2y^2=a^2b^2$$
$$b^2\frac{a^2}{3}+a^2y^2=a^2b^2$$
$$\frac{b^2}{3}+y^2=b^2$$
$$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}b$$

Answer (score 2):

just out of curiosity, we know that $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$, then by AM–GM inequality
$$1=\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{2b^2}+\frac{y^2}{2b^2}\geq 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^2}{a^2}\cdot\frac{y^2}{2b^2}\cdot\frac{y^2}{2b^2}}$$
the equality holds when 
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}=\frac{y^2}{2b^2}=\frac{y^2}{2b^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since you started off using Langrange multipliers, let’s continue down that path. Using the correct value for $g_y$, we have $$\begin{align}
y^2 &= 2b^2\lambda x \\
2xy &= 2a^2\lambda y
\end{align}$$ which upon eliminating $\lambda$ gives $$
a^2y^3 = 2b^2x^2y,
$$ so either $y=0$ or $a^2y^2=2b^2x^2$. Substituting this into the constraint: $$b^2x^2+2b^2x^2=a^2b^2 \\
\text{or} \\
x^2=\frac13a^2.$$ Plugging this back into the constraint and solving for $y$: $$\frac13a^2b^2+a^2y^2=a^2b^2 \\
\text{or} \\
y^2=\frac23b^2.$$ $f$ is an even function of $y$, so it doesn’t matter which root we use to test these points against $f$. $$
f\left(+\sqrt{\frac13}a,\pm\sqrt{\frac23}b\right) = {2\sqrt3 \over 9}ab^2 \\
\text{and} \\
f\left(-\sqrt{\frac13}a,\pm\sqrt{\frac23}b\right) = -{2\sqrt3 \over 9}ab^2
$$ We still have $y=0$ as a candidate, but $f(x,0)=0$, so this doesn’t yield an extremum.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the equation of
$$g(x,y)=b^2x^2+a^2y^2=a^2b^2$$
You can then write $x$ as a function of $y$:
$$x=\pm\frac{1}{b}\sqrt{a^2b^2-a^2y^2}=\pm\frac{1}{ab}\sqrt{a^2-y^2}$$
You can then plug in your values that you found for $y$ from solving the second-to-last equation you gave (note that $y=0$ is a valid solution, as [Jack Bauer pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543654/finding-the-maximum-value/1543666#comment3143428_1543654), because of the function before you cancelled out the $y$s).

Comment: Did you set equal and solve like what Jack Bauer did?

Comment: @LittleJon No; I pointed you toward solving directly based on $a$ and $b$ based on the fact that you had already arrived at one of the possible values for $y$ (the reason that $y=0$ is also a possibility is that that satisfies the second-to-last equation you had, before you cancelled our the $y$s).